# Exit a while loop Java

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I can not get this loop to stop even though I set the count variable = to false. And it won't go to the next method called in the Main class. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Main Class

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Var V = new Var();
        End E = new End();

        V.enter();
        E.end();

    }

}
```

Var Class

```
public class Var {

    static int x = 0;
    static boolean count = true;


    public static void enter(){

        while (count = true ){
            x = x+10;
            System.out.println(x);
            count = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your assignment of `count = true` instead of the comparison `count == true` means that you effectively just have `while (true)`, thus resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: The usual trick that helps avoid this kind of errors is to put the constant on the left hand side of the operator, like so: `while (true == count)`. If you use the assignment operator `=` instead of the comparison operator `==` by mistake the compiler will tell you that right away, detecting an attempt to assign a value to a constant.

Comment: @mustaccio No, it's not. The correct way to do this in Java is `while(count)` - there is absolutely no reason to compare it to anything.

Comment: @Brian Roach: "_The correct way_"? According to who?

Comment: Anyone with common sense? Why would you add a redundant and useless comparison? Why even introduce the possibility of accidentally typing `=` instead of `==` and triggering a compiler error? Please, explain why that is a good idea and the proper approach over simply evaluating the boolean which eliminates the issue entirely.

Answer (score 5):

replace

```
while (count = true ){
```

with

```
while (count == true ){
```

or simply

```
while(count){
   ...
}
```

Comment: The reason for this is that `count = true` assigns the value of `true` to the variable `count` which then returns the value `true` to the while-loop and thus going infinite since even if it was false, it'd now become true. This is basically the same as @ Quetzalcoatl comment.

Comment: The better answer would be `while (count) { ... }` ; there is no reason to compare it to anything in Java.

Comment: I wanted the author to see that he was doing the assignation. I edited the answer to add this solution. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
while (count = true) {
```

to

```
while (count) {
```

The expression `count = true` is an assignment, not a comparison, which would use a relational operator. The result of an assignment expression is the assigned value, which in this case is always `true`.

Comparing a boolean expression to a boolean literal (that is, `count == true` or `((x && y) || z) == false`) is ugly and confusing. Just use the expression itself (`count` or `!((x && y) || z)`).

Answer (score 2):

Even this should work as count is already boolean.
single equal to in `while (count =true ){` causes count to changed to true?
`

```
 public class Var {

    static int x = 0;
    static boolean count = true;


    public static void enter(){

        while (count  ){
            x = x+10;
            System.out.println(x);
            count = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `while (count = true)` uses the assignment operator, not the equality operator. The assignment operator returns the variable's value after assignment - in this case, `true` ([reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26)).

> At run time, the result of the assignment expression is the value of the variable after the assignment has occurred. The result of an assignment expression is not itself a variable.

So your loop is effectively this:

```
while (true){
    count = true;
    x = x+10;
    System.out.println(x);
    count = false;
}
```

To fix this you can use the equality operator `==` or just `while (count)`. The latter is better style, but both work.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
while (count = true) {
```

to

```
while (count == true) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (count = true ){
            x = x+10;
            System.out.println(x);
            count = false;
        }
```

in here you use `count = true`.  it is a asign operation which will always return true.

So you `count == true` to compare.